# ajax call to .ashx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

Can someone please check why my .ashx file is not firing
the alert is being hit fine

```
function setHeartbeat() {
        setInterval("heartbeat()", 20000); 
           }

         function heartbeat() {
             alert('ajax called');
                 $.ajax({
                     type: "GET",
                     url: "SessionHeartbeat.ashx",
                     data: null,
                     success: function (data) {
                         beatHeart(30);
                         setHeartbeat();

    }});
    }
```

.ashx file looks like this and is called SessionHeartbeat.ashx

```
public class SessionHeartbeat : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
    {
        public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Session["Heartbeat"] = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}
```

this is my web.config

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="SessionHeartbeat.ashx" validate="false" type="SessionHeartbeat"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

Comment: Why don't you provide an `error` function and see what it might tell you?

Comment: The handler is not writting anything in response.

Comment: I was trying to implement this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431733/keeping-asp-net-session-open-alive  (But couldnt get it to work - I re-did the ajax query in a format I can understand but this doesnt work as well)

Comment: have you registered that handler? are you adding `<httpHandlers>...</httpHandlers>` bit into system.web section of web.config?

Comment: yes they are in the <system.web> tag

Comment: in `configuration` section add `<system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    </system.webServer>` With that change it worked here.

Comment: I already had that defined in the web.config

Comment: @derloopkat You don't need to register generic handlers (ashx). That's only neceessary for non-generic handlers, the kind that lacks an ashx file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use handler class, you have to add them to `<httpHandlers>` tag inside web.config.

What you have is a ***generic handler***. You do not need to do anything, so remove it from `<httpHandlers>` tag inside web.config.

The following code should work as long as you can access  `SessionHeartbeat.ashx` from client browser.

```
<script>

    setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "<%= ResolveUrl("~/SessionHeartbeat.ashx") %>",
            data: null,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('Heartbeat called at ' + data);
            }
        });
    }, 20000);

</script>

public class SessionHeartbeat : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var dateTimeNow = DateTime.Now;
        context.Session["Heartbeat"] = dateTimeNow;
        context.Response.Write(dateTimeNow);
    }

    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }
}
```

Comment: thank this worked for me fine although I deleted my .ashx file and recreated it and then it started working - you were correct I didn't need it in the web.config file - thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

The example you mentioned worked after updating web.config:

```
<configuration>
      <!--Other settings-->
      <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
      </system.webServer>
      <system.web>
          <httpHandlers>
             <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="SessionHeartbeat.ashx" validate="false" type="SessionHeartbeat"/>
          </httpHandlers>
      </system.web>
</configuration>
```

But this depends on IIS version and how it's configured. See this answer: [Generic Handler not working on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7907938/2516718). It explains that a Generic Handler still needs settings in your web.config in some scenarios and that was the case when I've followed the example in the link you posted.

Also I have previously added response write in ProcessRequest

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.Write("Hello World");
    context.Session["Heartbeat"] = DateTime.Now;
}
```

If you deploy this in IIS you probably will need to [register your handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) but it was not necessary in my IIS Express.

Comment: yes that's being called fine the ajax function is also being called as the alert is firing